# Remove Launcher icon background in Android Tablet

Tags: android

I have created application for both `Tablets` and `Mobile phones`, the problem is when application is launched in Mobile phones, launcher icon appears good, with no background as original icon does not have background but when application is launched in Tablet, system creates the icon background as the image is attached. [image]

> Can anyone please help me out how to remove the background from the
>   launcher icon?

**APPLIST IMAGE**

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with phones or tablets. Tablets do not magically add icon backgrounds. Home screens might, but they might do so on any size screen, not just tablets.

Comment: On tablet, some applications don't have background. You can see that DVR icon is placed in the white background. I don't want that background?

Comment: Your icon appears to be a lot smaller than the others. Perhaps this particular home screen applies backgrounds to small icons when the home screen is showing some wallpaper.

Comment: I have resized the icon to larger size but system still shows the background. I have app icon of size 512 x 512 which shows the background, I have resized the icon to 1024 x 1024, background is still there

Comment: @CommonsWare: How to create big icons? I have increased the size from 512 x 512 to 1024 x 1024 but still it shows in the background?

Comment: @CommonsWare: What is the recommended launcher icon size for 7" tablets so that background does not appear?

Comment: This has nothing to do with 7" tablets. It has everything to do with this particular home screen implementation on this particular tablet. Contact the developers of this home screen implementation and ask *them* what to do.

Comment: @CommonsWare: That means its not icon issue, its their implementation how they are treating these icons?

Comment: Correct. They are using some algorithm to decide to put a background behind it, presumably to provide contrast against the wallpaper. The only people who can tell you what that algorithm is are the people who wrote that algorithm. Bear in mind that there are thousands of Android device models, which ship with hundreds of home screen implementations, and users can download their own home screen apps from the Play Store and elsewhere. None of them have to even *show* icons, let alone do so in a way that you like. Home screens can do what they want, so I suggest that you stop worrying about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because of your phone and tablet have different theme. According to theme it display the launcher icon background. 
[image: It take background by deafault]

Comment: On tablet, some applications don't have background. You can see that DVR icon is placed in the white background. I don't want that background?

Comment: send me the screen shot of  app list screen of your tablet

Comment: I have attached icon of the app which have background. You want snapshot from Settings/Manage Apps -> All Apps ??

Comment: no. 
screenshot Like this.
http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/384x640xgoogle-experience-launcher-app-drawer.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.pzw_hS1LCz.png

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I take default background. So you have to change the resolution of you app icon...

Comment: How to create big icons? I have increased the size from 512 x 512 to 1024 x 1024 but still it shows in the background?

Comment: What is the recommended launcher icon size for 7" tablets?

Comment: use https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html for creating icon